# Java: Value repeats in array from input of user

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I have written a code to get values from users 5 times, but only allow to enter only unique values, However it does not work the right way ( The part validating if it is a unique value or no )

Here is code:

```
for (int answerUserTries = 0; answerUserTries < 5; answerUserTries++) {
    System.out.println("Please enter the number");
    int answerUser = in.nextInt();
    for (int w=0;w<5;w++ ) {
        if (answerArray[w] == answerUser) {
            System.out.println("Please enter the number REPEATING NUMBER");
            w=6;
        }
        else {
            answerArray[w] = answerUser;
        }
}
```

It work fine, but when I put non-unique value into array as a result it writes that it is non-unique value, however it only have 5 inputs, and when i put non-unique value input is also counts. How can i fix it? Here is result of running code:

```
Please enter the number
1
Please enter the number
1
Repeating Number
Please enter the number
1
Repeating Number
Please enter the number
1
Repeating Number
Please enter the number
1
Repeating Number
```

And then program stops

Comment: well the loops run 5 times only `for (int answerUserTries = 0; answerUserTries < 5; answerUserTries++)`

Comment: So, you want 5 unique numbers.  That means you can't have a loop from 0 to 5, because you don't know how many tries it will take.  You need a `while` loop instead.  Bump `answerUserTries` only when there is a successful add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bump the counter only when you have success.  You only need to search through as many answers as you have received, and you need to add your entry at `answerUserTries`, not at `w`:

```
int answerUserTries = 0;
while(answerUserTries < 5) {
    System.out.println("Please enter the number");
    int answerUser = in.nextInt();
    bool success = true;
    for (int w=0;w<answerUserTries;w++ ) {
        if (answerArray[w] == answerUser) {
            System.out.println("Please enter the number REPEATING NUMBER");
            success = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if( success ) {
        answerArray[answerUserTries] = answerUser;
        answerUserTries++;
    }
}
```